# form fields in angular not displaying already populated data when trying to create an update function

Tags: html, node.js, angular, typescript, mean

I am creating a MEAN application that can perform CRUD operations, however when i am creating the update function the form fields are not populated with the already existing data to be updated.
HTML:

```
<button
              mat-button
              color="basic"
              [routerLink]="['/moc-report', mocreport._id]"
            >
              Update Status
            </button>
```

This is the button but to update but the form does not contain the data needed to update:
HTML of the form to contain the data to be updated:

```
<div class="container">
  <!--Navbar-->
  <mat-toolbar color="primary">
    <div class="centerNavBar">
      <a mat-button href="fa-dashboard">Back</a>
      &nbsp;
      <span class="headSpacer">Damage Assessment Tool</span>
      &nbsp;
      <a mat-button href="">Logout</a>
    </div>
  </mat-toolbar>
</div>

<div>
  <mat-sidenav-container class="MainContainter">
    <!--SideNav-->
    <mat-sidenav mode="side" opened>
      <div>
        <a mat-button href="">Message Board</a>
      </div>
    </mat-sidenav>
    <mat-sidenav-content class="MainContent">
      <mat-card>
        <mat-card-header class="sect">Create report:</mat-card-header>
        <br /><br />
        <mat-card-content class="centerAlign">
          <!--Div for form-->
          <div>
            <form [formGroup]="form" (submit)="addMOCForm()">
              <mat-form-field class="formwidth">
                <input
                  matInput
                  class="form-control"
                  formControlName="MoCReportDateTime"
                  type="Date"
                  required
                />
              </mat-form-field>
              <br />
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Comment</mat-label>
                <input
                  placeholder="--"
                  matInput
                  formControlName="MoCDescription"
                  class="form-control"
                  type="string"
                  required
                />
              </mat-form-field>
              <br />
              <mat-form-field>
                <mat-label>Facility In Question</mat-label>
                <input
                  placeholder="--"
                  matInput
                  formControlName="facilityName"
                  class="form-control"
                  type="string"
                  required
                />
              </mat-form-field>
              <mat-card class="centerAlign">
                <mat-card-actions>
                  <!--Div for buttons-->
                  <div>
                    <input
                      style="display: none"
                      #ImageInput
                      type="file"
                      (change)="onFileSelected($event)"
                    />

                    <button
                      mat-raised-button
                      type="button"
                      (click)="ImageInput.click()"
                    >
                      Upload Images
                    </button>
                    &nbsp;
                    <button mat-raised-button color="primary" type="submit">
                      Add
                    </button>
                  </div>
                </mat-card-actions>
              </mat-card>
            </form>
          </div>
        </mat-card-content>
      </mat-card>
    </mat-sidenav-content>
  </mat-sidenav-container>
</div>
```

TS:

```
import { AfterViewInit, Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import {
  FormBuilder,
  FormGroup,
  FormControl,
} from '@angular/forms';

import { HttpClient } from '@angular/common/http';

import { MOCReportService } from 'src/app/service/mocreport.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-moc-report',
  templateUrl: './moc-report.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./moc-report.component.css'],
})
export class MocReportComponent implements OnInit {
  
  image: any;
  Image = [];
  imageData: any;

  constructor(
    private mocreportservice: MOCReportService,
    //private mapService: MocMapService,
    private router: Router,
    private fb: FormBuilder,
    private http: HttpClient
  ) {}
  form = new FormGroup({
    facilityName: new FormControl(''),
    MoCDescription: new FormControl(''),
    MoCReportDateTime: new FormControl(''),
  });

  

  onFileSelected(event: any) {
    const file = (event.target as HTMLInputElement).files;
    this.form.patchValue({ Image: file });
    const allowedMimeTypes = ['image/png', 'image/jpeg', 'image/jpg'];

    {
      const reader = new FileReader();
      reader.onload = () => {
        this.imageData = reader.result as string;
      };
      if (file) {
        reader.readAsDataURL(file[0]);
      }
    }
    console.log(event.target.files[0]);
    const Image = event.target.files[0];
    this.image = Image;
  }

  addMOCForm() {
    console.log('adding');this.MoCReportDateTime, this.mocImage);
    const formData = new FormData();
    formData.append('facilityName', this.form.value.facilityName);
    formData.append('MoCDescription', this.form.value.MoCDescription);
    formData.append(
      'MoCReportDateTimeString',
      this.form.value.MoCReportDateTimeString
    );
    formData.append('mocImage', this.image);
    this.mocreportservice.postMOCForm(formData).subscribe((d) => {
      console.log(d);
    });
    this.router.navigate(['/message-board']);
  }
  
  ngOnInit(): void {}
}
```

Comment: You want the forms to be already be populated by some kind of data when the component initializes?

Comment: yes i do, the data to be updated

Comment: I could not see the code where you have fetched those data to be updated.
You have to get the data first, then you will have to set those data in the respective form control on initializtion.

Answer (score 0):

your question is missing two things - 1.code to update the form values is missing. 2.what values you want to update in the form and where are they in the code snippet provided above.

Still I am providing you the solution
1.First update your html and add a click event which will be used for updating the form on click of button

HTML:

```
<button
      mat-button
      color="basic"
      [routerLink]="['/moc-report', mocreport._id]"
      (click)="onUpdateClik()">
      Update Status
    </button>
```

TS:

```
onUpdateClik(){
        //I'm assuming you want to update the form values which you are getting in form from the template.
        //If you are getting the form values from any API then append those values and you'll be done.
        this.form.patchValue({
            facilityName: this.form.value.facilityName, //update your respective values
            MoCDescription: this.form.value.MoCDescription, //update your respective values
            MoCReportDateTime: this.form.value.MoCReportDateTimeString, //update your respective values
        })
        }
```